# The idea of Blockchain compression

Tags: blockchain, decentralization

Bitcoin's blockchain is large. By accident, I discovered a way to reduce it (on the disk), but I wonder why it was not implemented by someone else.

I wrote a short documentation here: http://194.28.50.88/BTC-Compression/btc-compression.pdf

I would like to know your opinions.

PS. Maybe it is possible to adapt this compression to get more transations into block

Comment: This is a question looking to start a discussion, which is off topic for a Q&A site.